# is it possible to show all labels of WMS layer at any extent without SLD ol5?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I am showing WMS layer that shows label on it by defining SLD in GeoServer. The problem is that is is not showing all labels at particular extent.

[image]

But when I zoom in, all labels are displayed.
[image]

My problem is that I am exporting the map at some extent then all label is not showing when I see the PDF.

Is it possible to show all labels in map PDF?

Answer (score 3):

GeoServe tries to apply basic cartographic good practice and not have labels that overlap (as no one can read those). If you really want to you can prevent this from happening by adding some [vendor parameters](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html):

```
<VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>
<VendorOption name="spaceAround">-1</VendorOption>
<VendorOption name="partials">true</VendorOption>
```

Comment: thanks sir. where to put this code in SLD?